# False installation process and I cant even get on Bios!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I guess I had set the primary or secondary boot device wrongly!
my laptop is a sony vaio t serie and has a win 8.1 .

I have download the ubuntu 10.13 from the website and instead of burn it on a DVD or CD, made a USB-Stick boot device.

I got into bios and disabled the secure boot since it couldn't start the booting by itself at restart.
after getting to ubuntu installation shield, it couldn't recognized a place to install.
I faced some errors and just could force shut-down by pressing and holding the power key!
now!!!!
I can't install ubuntu... cant get on my bios... f8 doesn't work and when put the USB-stick out and restard my laptop it just says: `OPERATING SYSTEM NOT FOUND...`

only thing that work now is to sick on USB and selecting "try Ubuntu without installation"...

anyone who knows how to fix this?

thank you

Comment: It may be that your partitions are messed up. I would recommend booting from the Live USB and selecting 'Try Ubuntu without installation'. Then open GParted and see if your partitions are ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter in your bios using the ASSIST button and enable again the secure boot: https://superuser.com/questions/499037/how-to-enter-bios-setup-in-sony-vaio-svt11125cgs

Answer (score 0):

If you are still able to boot from CD, I would recommend downloading RescaTux or Gparted Live (http://gparted.org/livecd.php), and repairing your partitions. If you have a spare computer, you may be able to boot Gparted Live from USB and attempt the repair.
The problem seems to be a corrupted partition table, and the only fix I know is to manually repair by live USBs/ CDs, or placing the hard drive into another computer and repairing that way.